# I'm unable to create this Design using CSS?

Tags: html, css

**I want to create something like this as shown in the picture down below.**

I want to write some content inside these shapes as shown in **Figure** but from my code, my content **comes out** from these shapes, and In my **code**, my div containing gaps as you can see after running my code **Screen Size**.

**Note :** I already tried [W3school Css Shape.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp) also,
I'm already read about **Clip-path** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive)

**Important:** I already tried all  **related answers** but none of them **helpful** for me.

**Already Tried these answers :** [Answer No.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) , [Answer No.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180627/how-to-create-a-slanted-transparent-shape-with-background-image) , [Answer No.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308745/creating-a-angled-shape-with-css3) , [Answer No.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308745/creating-a-angled-shape-with-css3) , [Answer No.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68131654/wrap-text-content-inside-a-clip-path-polygontriangle-shape-and-image-clipped-o)

**Output I want to achive**: [image: Output]

**Output I'm getting from my Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
     .clipped-text  {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clipped-text:before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background-color: white;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path:     polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

.clipped  {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clipped:before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(212, 55, 55);
  shape-outside: inset(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path:     inset(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

.clip-text  {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clip-text:before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background-color: white;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path:     polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

    </style>
<p class="clipped-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <div class="clipped">Some text inside it..
  
</div>
<p class="clipped-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me with the **Source Code** please I tried All of the related solutions none of them are helping me.

Comment: at least try to play with the clip-path value to invert the second trinagle, you already did the first one. someone commented in your old question a tool to help you with : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68871730/8620333

Comment: and the middle element is a common element, why adding clip-path or shape outside to it?

Comment: Bro I tried all of these nothing helped me :( can you please help me with source code?

Comment: I tried tool too but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. I just reversed the triangle in your clip-path and shape-outside.

```css
.clipped-text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
}

.clipped-text:before {
  --clipped-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  content: "";
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  shape-outside: var(--clipped-path);
  clip-path: var(--clipped-path);
}

.mirrored.clipped-text::before {
  float: left;
  --clipped-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}

main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(212, 55, 55);
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<p class="clipped-text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</p>
<main>
  Some text inside it..
</main>
<p class="mirrored clipped-text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</p>
```